# Visual Basic 2010 DataGridView Filter is not working

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datasource, datetimepicker

Both code snippets don't work. 
My column name is `Shipment End` in `DataGridView1`

```
Dim az As Date = DateTimePicker3.Value
Dim bz As Date = DateTimePicker4.Value
Me.Sheet1BindingSource.Filter = "([Shipment End]<= '" & DateTimePicker3.Value & "' and [Shipment End]>= '" & DateTimePicker4.Value & ")"
```

and

```
Dim DateFrom As String = String.Format("Shipment End >= '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' ", DateTimePicker3.Value)
Dim DateTo As String = String.Format("Shipment End <= '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' ", DateTimePicker4.Value)
```

Comment: Please elaborate, what are you trying to do. What do you mean, dont work? you get an error or not the expected result?

Comment: i get an error of syntax

Comment: `'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}'` the ticks are forcing your date time value to text!